# In vba project explorer what was sheet1 is now showing sheet1 and sheet11, messing up my macros

Tags: excel, excel-365

I have a workbook that had sheet1 set up as "General Journal" with macros.
For some reason it nows shows sheet1 and sheet11 as "General Journal"

[project explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpAXU.png)

Is there a reason this happens and any means of fixing

[what is hould look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwAlL.png)Sheet

Comment: This doesn't happen spontaneously. In your screenshot it looks like you've run some code and created a new file. The reason for the sheet naming is probably somewhere in that code. If you want to fix the code, you'd have to show the code here. If you want to change the sheet names to something else, you can do it in the Properties window. And, it's better to refer to your sheets by their name instead of their index number to avoid this problem altogether.

Comment: I would probably assume my workbook is corrupted and go back to a backup (you do have frequent backups, right?!). Or move code and data to a new workbook for a fresh start.

Comment: Thanks for your responses but that does not solve it. I just opened the file again and now it has shifted to Sheet111 compounding the error again.  Very frustrating because it does not make sense.

Comment: No solution has been presented because you haven't shown the code that needs to be fixed. If you show the code, someone can probably show you what needs to be fixed.

Comment: *Thanks for your responses but that does not solve it.* What did you try?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.